# Direct computer to computer video chat

Tags: windows, chat

I would have thought it would be common but I can't find one currently; I'm looking for a chat protocol/app that:

- Runs directly between two computers (could be client-server relationship I don't really care about that) - without going to a third-party host (ie Skype/Google Hangouts). Yes I know it will go through ISPs etc. but I want it to be able to be direct between the two computers other than that.
- Easy to *use* (don't care about *ease of **initial setup*** as I'd do that myself).
- Supports audio, video, and text.
- Beyond chat application provide no access to the other computer.
- Free (preferred).
- Open-Source (preferred).
- Bonus: have a built in gaming options (like chess etc.)
- Bonus: some form of encryption
- Windows preferred - if client-server linux is fine for server.

Comment: Video is in the TODO list of open source client/server voice chat software Mumble: http://mumble.sourceforge.net/To-Do_List#Video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've settled on the best option being a self-hosted XMPP Server; I'm thinking that the best for my purposes/system is [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/). With as a client looking at [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) right now.

To go over my requirements:

- *Runs directly between two computers (could be client-server relationship I don't really care about that) - without going to a third-party host (ie Skype/Google Hangouts). Yes I know it will go through ISPs etc. but I want it to be able to be direct between the two computers other than that:* Yes and can work with a massive variety of chat clients.
- *Easy to **use** (don't care about ease of **initial setup** as I'd do that myself):* Yes; most clients are anyways and Jitsi is certainly.
- *Supports audio, video, and text.:* XMPP RFC does delineate support for all of those, Openfire supports all of those and many clients do; Jitsi certainly does.
- *Beyond chat application provide no access to the other computer.:* Yes - though it can be configured to do some more things like file sharing.
- *Free (preferred).:* Yes - both Jitsi and Open
- *Open-Source (preferred).:* Yes - both Jitsi and Openfire are free.
- *Bonus: have a built in gaming options (like chess etc.):* That would be configured per client so far I haven't found a client with that and audio/video.
- *Bonus: some form of encryption:* Yes can be configured with SSL/TLS options.
- *Windows preferred - if client-server linux is fine for server.:* Multiplatform :D

Answer (score 2):

[**Linphone**](http://www.linphone.org/):

- voice, video or text messaging
- freeware / open-source
- multi-platform (even mobile)
- uses [SIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) protocol - no need for server

According to the documentation it should work:

> Just enter sip: in the SIP url bar of linphone to place a call to another linphone running in your network.
>
> **This works also on the public internet** provided that the two machines have public IP addresses or appropriate firewall rules.

[image]

Comment: Have you used it in a *non local* situation - and do you know if it accepts ports as well as IP address?

Comment: The only problem is the appropriate firewall/public IP requirement. I'm fine with that but depending on the situation not everyone can set that up easily.