# Open source video-conference Skype-Like

Tags: linux, open-source, c, video-conferencing, skype

I am looking for an *open-source* video-conference Skype-Like software for Linux Mint 17.

the main feature it should have is an **end-to-end** connection, without having NAT, so a low-level encryption.

it would be great if written in C.

NB. I don't really need to use the chat, what i need is having a video-conference with another client and establish a p2p direct connection between me and him.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm looking for a software which handles sockets. For example there should be a file called socket.c (something like that or at least a fire where they're handled). The fact is i have to send some data on the socket the software open between 2 clients during a video-conference.

Comment: Related: [Skype alternative for Linux with counterpart for Android](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11714/185) / [Free/Libre voice & video chat alternative to Skype?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/243/185) / [Skype client alternative for Ubuntu](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10060/185) / [Direct computer to computer video chat](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3594/185) … in short: Linphone?

Comment: I saw Linphone, but looking at the code i can't find where the socket are handled..

Comment: Is that required for using the software? I wasn't aware of that. Can you please elaborate? Your question doesn't contain any details for that.

Comment: edited the post. I clearly was too general on description! :)

Comment: Should the software support video conferences with multiple clients or with single? Utox (lightweight tox client) fits in the latter case

Comment: @Basionkler I'm a bit confused: are you looking for software to use – or for example code using certain functionality? Because for *using* software, you don't necessarily need its source code.

Comment: @ayvango not really, a client-to-client single video-conference it's enough for what i need! I'm going to have a look with utox :D


Izzy yes, i know asking for source code is not required here, but maybe there are some people here who used to have the same issue i'm experiencing and have a wide knowledge about linux platform, more than i've got :)